# mark the certain message as read via gmail api (using Oauth)

Tags: gmail

is there anyway of that we can mark or flag the certain message as READ via the GMAIL API using the Oauth 2.0 like we can read the feed via Gmail API ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the a way to set the status READ to a message via the GMAIL API. So I used the IMAP to authenticate with the Oauth Access Token and use IMAP to get the functionality that I want.